# Only displaying zip files with wp media

Tags: javascript, media, media-library, media-modal

I'm using `wp.media()` to invoke the WordPress media library modal in a custom taxonomy.  In the pop up I only want to display zip files. I know I can limit the media library to just audio or video using those keywords but there doesn't seem to be a comprehensive list of "types" anywhere.

How would I get `wp.media()` to only display zip files?

Currently I have:

```
// Sets up the media library frame
meta_image_frame = wp.media.frames.meta_image_frame = wp.media({
    title: meta_term_image.title,
    button: { text:  meta_term_image.button },
    library: { type: "zip"}
});
```

Needless to say `type: "zip"` doesn't work.  However `type: "audio"` works just fine.

Comment: Zip looks like it's actually a sub-type of `application`. Have you tried `type: 'application/zip'`?

Comment: That does it thanks!  I hadn't realised it just referred to MIME Types. Do you want to provide that as an answer?

Comment: I wasn't certain it would work but glad to hear it did! I've add my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zip files are in a subtype called `application` so you should try using:

`type: 'application/zip'`

A list of default allowed mime types is available from [wp_get_mime_types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_allowed_mime_types#Default_allowed_mime_types).